# Beautiful Soup error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am getting this error:

```
---> 14 content = s.find_all('p')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

While running the script below:

```
r = requests.get('https://www.marketsandmarkets.com/Market-Reports/rocket-missile-market-203298804.html/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
s = soup.find('div', class_='entry-content') 
content = s.find_all('p')
print(content)
```

It's working for some URLs, but for other URLs it gives an attribute error. Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: The HTML you fetched does not contain any div with class `entry-content`. I checked: `"entry-content" in str(requests.get("https://www.marketsandmarkets.com/Market-Reports/rocket-missile-market-203298804.html/").content)` gives False

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `soup.find` does not find anything, it returns `None`. Guard your `s.find_all` call with `if s:` or `if s in not None:`.

So your code becomes:

```
r = requests.get('https://www.marketsandmarkets.com/Market-Reports/rocket-missile-market-203298804.html/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
s = soup.find('div', class_='entry-content') 
if s is not None:
    content = s.find_all('p')
    print(content) 
else:
    print("Didn't find what I was looking for...")
```

or maybe:

```
content = s.find_all('p') if s is not None else []
print(content)
```

Ref: https://crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find

Comment: Can be shortened `if s is not None:` to `if s:`

Comment: Agreed but I actually prefer being more explicit when I know `None` is the actual return value.

Comment: https://pep8.org (search for "is not None" in there) even says "Also, beware of writing `if x` when you really mean `if x is not None` – e.g. when testing whether a variable or argument that defaults to None was set to some other value." For this code, the semantics would be the same, but from this PEP8 recommendation I have taken the habit to prefer `is not None` whenever it's correct.